model.fit() class weights do not work when training the model
when calculating classes_weight with
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight="balanced",
                     classes=np.unique(masks_reshaped_encoded),y= masks_reshaped_encoded)

I get the weights but when using keras model.fit() this error is shown
history=model.fit(img, msk, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=False,
                  class_weight=class_weights)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get'enter image description here
I am using this code
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
import imageio
import numpy as np
import keras
import glob
import random
import os
os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"
import segmentation_models as sm
#import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from model_segmentation import simple_unet_model
from keras.metrics import MeanIoU
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


img = img[...,np.newaxis]
print(img.shape)
print(msk.shape)
#msk = msk[...,np.newaxis]
kernel_initializer =  'he_uniform' #Try others if you want

steps_per_epoch = len(train_img_list)//batch_size
#val_steps_per_epoch = len(val_img_list)//batch_size

model = simple_unet_model(IMG_HEIGHT=128, IMG_WIDTH=128, IMG_CHANNELS=1, num_classes=4)

total_loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
#metrics = ['accuracy', sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5)]
metrics = ['accuracy']
optim = 'adam'

model.compile(optimizer = optim, loss=total_loss, metrics= metrics)
print(model.summary())

print(model.input_shape)
print(model.output_shape)

msk = msk.astype(np.uint8)
print(msk.shape)
msk_argmax=np.argmax(msk, axis=3)
masks_reshaped = msk_argmax.reshape(-1,1)
print(masks_reshaped.shape)
masks_reshaped_encoded = masks_reshaped.reshape(-1)
print(masks_reshaped_encoded.shape)

labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
masks_reshaped_encoded = labelencoder.fit_transform(masks_reshaped)
print(masks_reshaped_encoded.shape)

np.unique(masks_reshaped_encoded)


thank you very much for your help

From keras documantation:

class_weight: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to
a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during
training only).

But sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight returns ndarray.
So basically you need to convert received weights to pairs class: weight. This question may be helpful

thanks for your response, I made the change for integer values but I got this new error when trying to train the model    TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

@oliver6626 could you update your question with new code and new error so I could reproduce it?

create this dictionary with integer values class_weights_manual= {0:1, 1:2, 2:4, 3:8} history=model.fit(img, msk, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=False, class_weight=class_weights_manual)   when doing that I got this error TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars   maybe the data set should have some specific format?

It is difficult to say why you're getting this error without seeing your code. First thing I would check is X and y arrays you pass to fit(). Maybe it is a good idea to create new question regarding this problem where you could attach full code and reproducible X and y data.
